# How to decide a basketball game ended but not yet end of regulation

Tags: rules, basketball

We got a basketball game with score 56-61 4:40 mins remaining in the fourth quarter. Then game can't continue because of power outage (night). How should we decide on the game? Shall we continue on another day? Shall we declare the leading team as the winner?

Answer (score 2):

On the assumption you're playing in some sort of organised tournament, ask the organisers.

Comment: Are there no FIBA rules on this?

Comment: Not within the official rules. Doing so (for any sport) would be pretty much impossible because the circumstances can vary so much - what is fair and equitable in one situation (a team leading by 20 with one second on the clock) would be patently stupid in another (a team leading by one point 10 seconds into the match).